# Background color not applying

Tags: html, css

I'm new in web programming and I'm actually learning html and css and I have a problem applying background color in some parts of my web page.
Can someone help me to apply the background color in the header as I've done in my footer. Don't know why it is not working on the header.I've tried to set the same background color to the childs of the header but it is a dirt solution and does not look nice. 
Thanks.

index.html

```
<header>
        <div class="logo">
          <h2 class="logo">Notflix</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="searchBarDiv">
          <form class="searchBar" action="index.html" method="post">
            <input class="bar" type="text" name="content">
            <input type="submit" value="Search"
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="cart">
          <img class="cartImg" src="images/cart.png" alt="cartImage">
        </div>
</header>
    <aside class="lateralMenu">

    </aside>
    <footer>
      <h4 class="devInfo">Copyright &copy; Miguel Olivera Cardo Madrid, Spain</h4>
    </footer>
```

style.css

```
body {
  margin: 0 0
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #CECDCC;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.logo {
  position: fixed;
  width: 25%;
}

.logo h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.searchBarDiv{
  position: fixed;
  width:50%;
  left:25%;
  top:2.5%;
}

.bar {
  width: 80%;

}
.cart {
  position: fixed;
  width: 25%;
  left:75%;
}

.cartImg {
  width:12%;
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-left: 31%;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom:0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #CECDCC;
}

.devInfo {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Try giving the header a fixed height. I assume it is 0 because of the fixed positioning.

Answer (score 0):

Everything inside the header is `position: fixed`, so it is taken out of normal flow.

Since there is nothing inside the header which *is* in normal flow, there is nothing to cause the header to have any height.

Since it is zero pixels tall, you can't see any background.

If you want the elements inside the header to be side-by-side, lay them out using [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) instead of positioning.

Comment: How? Another div inside the header as a flexbox? This new div will be fixed too?

Comment: "Another div inside the header as a flexbox?" — No, set the header itself to `display: flex` (and give its child elements suitable values for the `flex` property). Don't set **anything** inside the header to `position: fixed`.

Comment: But I want my header and all of its element to be fixed in order to see them even when I scroll down.

Comment: @moliverac8 — I didn't say to not set the header itself to something other than `position: fixed`

Comment: hi @Quentin, Flexbox Layout, Grid Layout and Floats are taken out of the normal flow? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You must set a `height` to the `header`

```css
body {
  margin: 0 0
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height:100px;;
  background-color: #CECDCC;
  overflow:hidden;
  
}

.logo {
  position: fixed;
  width: 25%;
}

.logo h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.searchBarDiv{
  position: fixed;
  width:50%;
  left:25%;
  top:2.5%;
}

.bar {
  width: 80%;

}
.cart {
  position: fixed;
  width: 25%;
  left:75%;
}

.cartImg {
  width:12%;
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-left: 31%;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom:0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #CECDCC;
}

.devInfo {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
        <div class="logo">
          <h2 class="logo">Notflix</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="searchBarDiv">
          <form class="searchBar" action="index.html" method="post">
            <input class="bar" type="text" name="content">
            <input type="submit" value="Search"
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="cart">
          <img class="cartImg" src="images/cart.png" alt="cartImage">
        </div>
</header>
    <aside class="lateralMenu">

    </aside>
    <footer>
      <h4 class="devInfo">Copyright &copy; Miguel Olivera Cardo Madrid, Spain</h4>
    </footer>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Your problem solve .**

```css
body {
  margin: 0 0 0 0 ;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #CECDCC;
  overflow: hidden;
  height:10%;
}


.logo {
  position: fixed;
  width: 25%;
  margin:0
}

.logo h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.searchBarDiv{
  position: fixed;
  width:50%;
  left:25%;
  top:2.5%;
}

.bar {
  width: 80%;

}
.cart {
  position: fixed;
  width: 25%;
  left:75%;
}

.cartImg {
  width:20%;
  float: right; 
  margin-right:10px;
  /*margin-top:20px;*/
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom:0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #CECDCC;
}

.devInfo {
  text-align: center;
}
.logo{
background-image:url('https://picsum.photos/id/1011/300/30');
background-repeat:  no-repeat;
color:white;
}
#inside-logo{
 position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<body>

    <header>
        <div id="inside-logo">
            <div class="logo">
                <h2 class="logo">Notflix</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="searchBarDiv">
                <form class="searchBar" action="index.html" method="post">
                    <input class="bar" type="text" name="content">
                    <input type="submit" value="Search">
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="cart">
                <img class="cartImg" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1011/30/30" alt="cartImage">
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <aside class="lateralMenu">

    </aside>

    <p>

        The syntax is strange because $.ajax predates the FormData. It’s easier with window.fetch! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
        adipisicing elit. Commodi nam harum pariatur, consectetur deleniti nulla iure ut! Ducimus ad esse harum iusto minus
        repudiandae, excepturi autem amet id. Ratione, accusantium. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        Amet esse corporis tempora quam assumenda minus atque fugiat possimus temporibus ipsam aspernatur, minima asperiores
        maxime! Aperiam quam, iste vitae assumenda sequi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem
        voluptate id minima ratione amet accusamus facere, quis commodi nam impedit. In at aliquid optio atque animi itaque
        dolorem facere cum.
        The syntax is strange because $.ajax predates the FormData. It’s easier with window.fetch! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
        adipisicing elit. Commodi nam harum pariatur, consectetur deleniti nulla iure ut! Ducimus ad esse harum iusto minus
        repudiandae, excepturi autem amet id. Ratione, accusantium. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        Amet esse corporis tempora quam assumenda minus atque fugiat possimus temporibus ipsam aspernatur, minima asperiores
        maxime! Aperiam quam, iste vitae assumenda sequi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem
        voluptate id minima ratione amet accusamus facere, quis commodi nam impedit. In at aliquid optio atque animi itaque
        dolorem facere cum.
        The syntax is strange because $.ajax predates the FormData. It’s easier with window.fetch! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
        adipisicing elit. Commodi nam harum pariatur, consectetur deleniti nulla iure ut! Ducimus ad esse harum iusto minus
        repudiandae, excepturi autem amet id. Ratione, accusantium. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        Amet esse corporis tempora quam assumenda minus atque fugiat possimus temporibus ipsam aspernatur, minima asperiores
        maxime! Aperiam quam, iste vitae assumenda sequi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem
        voluptate id minima ratione amet accusamus facere, quis commodi nam impedit. In at aliquid optio atque animi itaque
        dolorem facere cum.
        The syntax is strange because $.ajax predates the FormData. It’s easier with window.fetch! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
        adipisicing elit. Commodi nam harum pariatur, consectetur deleniti nulla iure ut! Ducimus ad esse harum iusto minus
        repudiandae, excepturi autem amet id. Ratione, accusantium. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        Amet esse corporis tempora quam assumenda minus atque fugiat possimus temporibus ipsam aspernatur, minima asperiores
        maxime! Aperiam quam, iste vitae assumenda sequi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem
        voluptate id minima ratione amet accusamus facere, quis commodi nam impedit. In at aliquid optio atque animi itaque
        dolorem facere cum.
        The syntax is strange because $.ajax predates the FormData. It’s easier with window.fetch! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
        adipisicing elit. Commodi nam harum pariatur, consectetur deleniti nulla iure ut! Ducimus ad esse harum iusto minus
        repudiandae, excepturi autem amet id. Ratione, accusantium. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        Amet esse corporis tempora quam assumenda minus atque fugiat possimus temporibus ipsam aspernatur, minima asperiores
        maxime! Aperiam quam, iste vitae assumenda sequi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem
        voluptate id minima ratione amet accusamus facere, quis commodi nam impedit. In at aliquid optio atque animi itaque
        dolorem facere cum.
        The syntax is strange because $.ajax predates the FormData. It’s easier with window.fetch! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
        adipisicing elit. Commodi nam harum pariatur, consectetur deleniti nulla iure ut! Ducimus ad esse harum iusto minus
        repudiandae, excepturi autem amet id. Ratione, accusantium. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        Amet esse corporis tempora quam assumenda minus atque fugiat possimus temporibus ipsam aspernatur, minima asperiores
        maxime! Aperiam quam, iste vitae assumenda sequi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem
        voluptate id minima ratione amet accusamus facere, quis commodi nam impedit. In at aliquid optio atque animi itaque
        dolorem facere cum.
        The syntax is strange because $.ajax predates the FormData. It’s easier with window.fetch! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
        adipisicing elit. Commodi nam harum pariatur, consectetur deleniti nulla iure ut! Ducimus ad esse harum iusto minus
        repudiandae, excepturi autem amet id. Ratione, accusantium. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        Amet esse corporis tempora quam assumenda minus atque fugiat possimus temporibus ipsam aspernatur, minima asperiores
        maxime! Aperiam quam, iste vitae assumenda sequi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem
        voluptate id minima ratione amet accusamus facere, quis commodi nam impedit. In at aliquid optio atque animi itaque
        dolorem facere cum.
        The syntax is strange because $.ajax predates the FormData. It’s easier with window.fetch! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
        adipisicing elit. Commodi nam harum pariatur, consectetur deleniti nulla iure ut! Ducimus ad esse harum iusto minus
        repudiandae, excepturi autem amet id. Ratione, accusantium. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        Amet esse corporis tempora quam assumenda minus atque fugiat possimus temporibus ipsam aspernatur, minima asperiores
        maxime! Aperiam quam, iste vitae assumenda sequi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem
        voluptate id minima ratione amet accusamus facere, quis commodi nam impedit. In at aliquid optio atque animi itaque
        dolorem facere cum.
        The syntax is strange because $.ajax predates the FormData. It’s easier with window.fetch! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
        adipisicing elit. Commodi nam harum pariatur, consectetur deleniti nulla iure ut! Ducimus ad esse harum iusto minus
        repudiandae, excepturi autem amet id. Ratione, accusantium. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        Amet esse corporis tempora quam assumenda minus atque fugiat possimus temporibus ipsam aspernatur, minima asperiores
        maxime! Aperiam quam, iste vitae assumenda sequi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem
        voluptate id minima ratione amet accusamus facere, quis commodi nam impedit. In at aliquid optio atque animi itaque
        dolorem facere cum.
        The syntax is strange because $.ajax predates the FormData. It’s easier with window.fetch! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
        adipisicing elit. Commodi nam harum pariatur, consectetur deleniti nulla iure ut! Ducimus ad esse harum iusto minus
        repudiandae, excepturi autem amet id. Ratione, accusantium. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        Amet esse corporis tempora quam assumenda minus atque fugiat possimus temporibus ipsam aspernatur, minima asperiores
        maxime! Aperiam quam, iste vitae assumenda sequi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem
        voluptate id minima ratione amet accusamus facere, quis commodi nam impedit. In at aliquid optio atque animi itaque
        dolorem facere cum.

    </p>

    <footer>
        <h4 class="devInfo">Copyright &copy; Miguel Olivera Cardo Madrid, Spain</h4>
    </footer>

</body>

</html>
```